# run application on xenapp by powershell

Tags: powershell, citrix, xenapp

I can login to xenapp by powershell:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("https://citrixurl")     
$ie.visible = $true    
$ie.document.getElementById('user').value = 'username'
$ie.document.getElementById('password').value = 'password'    
$ie.document.getElementById('btnLogin').click()
```

But I don't know how I can run specific application there.

Do I need Citrix Powershell SDK for this?

Comment: An SDK won't help you manipulate the webinterface-website. Look through the code to see if you can detect the button for the app you want. Might be hard/impossible though.

Comment: I don't think he wants to run internet explorer that was just an example app. He wants to run, someotherapp.exe

Comment: I have IE interface, where I see folders with applications. I want to open specific folder and run application inside,